# I have a problem in array.diff on codewars

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve the CodeWars challenge [Array.diff](https://www.codewars.com/kata/523f5d21c841566fde000009/train/java):

> Your goal in this kata is to implement a difference function, which subtracts one list from another and returns the result.
>
> It should remove all values from list `a`, which are present in list `b` keeping their order.
>
> ```
> Kata.arrayDiff(new int[] {1, 2}, new int[] {1}) => new int[] {2}
> ```
>
> If a value is present in `b`, all of its occurrences must be removed from the other:
>
> ```
> Kata.arrayDiff(new int[] {1, 2, 2, 2, 3}, new int[] {2}) => new int[] {1, 3}
> ```

Here is my code. What is my mistake?

```
    public static int[] arrayDiff(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] result;
        int size = a.length;
        if (a.length == 0 || b.length == 0) {
            return a
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                    if (a[j] == b[i]) {
                        size--;
                    }
                }
            }
            result = new int[size];
            int index = 0;
            int countEq = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                countEq = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                    if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                        countEq++;
                    }
                }
                if (countEq == 0) {
                    result[index] = a[i];
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I tried all sample tests, and the crucial tests that I could think off on NetBeans. Although it runs, the CodeWars framework did not accept my code.

Comment: In addition to what it says in the answer the kata seems to indicate that you must create a *new* array for the result. I wonder if this is also a requirement in the `a.length == 0 || b.length == 0` case. You could try.

Comment: It’s probably not what you want, but it might interest other readers to know that the method can be implemented more tersely as `return Arrays.stream(a) .filter(i -> ! Arrays.stream(b).anyMatch(j -> i == j)) .toArray();`-

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that `size--` could be executed too many times. For instance, if `a=[1,1,1]` and `b=[1,1,1]` then `size` will go from 3 to -6, which obviously is not intended. Consider that for a given `a[i]` there should be at most one execution of `size--`. So first loop over `a`, and then over `b`, and when you execute `size--` make sure to exit the inner loop.

Here is your code with the correction:

```
    public static int[] arrayDiff(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] result;
        int size = a.length;
        if (a.length == 0 || b.length == 0) {
            return a;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // First loop over A
                for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                    if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                        size--;
                        break; // Size must only decrease once per a[i]
                    }
                }
            }
            result = new int[size];
            int index = 0;
            int countEq = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                countEq = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                    if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                        countEq++;
                        break; // No need to look further
                    }
                }
                if (countEq == 0) {
                    result[index] = a[i];
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```